# Android: onClick callback with additional parameter?

Tags: android, buttonclick

Starting from this

```
<Button
            android:onClick="onBtnClicked"
            android:id="@+id/btn_edit_shared_preferences"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_show_map"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Edit Shared Preferences" />
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) says that the only parameter send to the onClick callback function is the View object.

Well, I might need some "extra-parameter", like in this case: I have a function that handles the lauching of activities, so it would be

```
openActivity(View v){..}
```

On the other hand, in the layout I would like to have

```
:onclick="openActivity(activityClassName)"
```

What is the right way to do something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `android:tag="YouActivity"` along with your `android:onClick="openActivity"`

now you can have `Activity` name in your `openActivity()` like this:

```
void openActivity(View v)
{
    String activityName = v.getTag().toString();
    Class<?> aClass = null;
    try {
            aClass = Class.forName("your.package."+activityName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startActivity(new Intent(this, aClass));
}
```

Comment: hi, is it possible to pass an argument which `onClick` method from xml?

Comment: thanks,+1vote i'm waiting for right answer . but your answer is also  right :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the View object only parameter which the `onClick` event gets but you can get more information through the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

A single button can correspond to a single method. There is no way to pass through extra paramaters.  For example, in your case, you want the button to launch an activity.  One way to do that is to write a method just for launching that activity.

```
<Button
        android:onClick="launchPreferencesActivity"
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit_shared_preferences"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_show_map"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Edit Shared Preferences" />
```

Then in your Activity:

```
public void launchPreferencesActivity(View v){
        //start Activity
}
```

Different buttons can correspond to different methods to handle the click event.  Or if you want, you can use the View parameter to distinguish what view is calling the method and handle it that way.

If there is some other factor going on that might change the behavior of the button, you can always change the onClickListener in code.  But generally, I would think the above approach works better for what your are trying to do.